# Unity 3D Display Lag

Tags: unity, graphics, performance

I find that there is quite a lot of lag when using Unity after upgrading to Precise. It seems that when I first start up the computer, everything is fine, but then if I put the computer on standy for a while and then come back to it, the display is extremely slow and there is a significant delay to visual effects that make the system rather cumbersome to use. I tried to report this as a bug but then bug reporting tool directed me to ask this is a question here first.

ATI Radeon Xpress 1250, proprietary ATI drivers are not available for this card with modern distributions since 2009. The effects have worked before on Unity but recently after each upgrade they have been degraded. I am now using the Gnome classic desktop which works wonderful even with effects but obviously I would like Unity to work.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Did you install any additional drivers? What is your specification?

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? (I don't have reputation to add comments yet, which is why I'm posting this as an answer). --- .pc

Comment: Yes I do have a swap partition. The issue seems to have got better recently, although after a while it slows down again, restarting the computer seems to make it more snappy again. It's not as bad as when I posted the original question.

Comment: I would say try installing *without* a swap partition.